# Як правильно: пта́­шок чи пташо́к?

Tags: іменники, наголос

У [словнику-довіднику](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%85) Жайворонка В. В. бачу, що наголос падає на перший склад:

> птах (зменшено-пестливе — **пт*а́*­шок**)

Однак у [СУМі-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/ptashok) дещо інша ситуація:

> **пташо́к** - те саме, що пташка.

Цікавить, як слід ставити наголос у цьому слові?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Словник відмінків](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKFwa.png)

[image]

[Відмінювання слів.](https://www.yenotes.com/uk/words/conjugation/search/?word=%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%BA&lang=uk)

Правильний варіант ***пташо́к***